# order by date sql

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to order a table by date, but get this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE `user_name` = 'felipe' LIMIT 0, 5' at line 1

If i delete the ORDER BY `file_time` it works properly ..

Any ideas ?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY `file_time` WHERE `user_name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}' LIMIT $start, $per_page")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE `user_name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}' ORDER BY `file_time` LIMIT $start, $per_page")
```

Answer (score 2):

the order of your query is mixed:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY `file_time` WHERE `user_name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}' LIMIT $start, $per_page")
```

should be

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files  WHERE `user_name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}' ORDER BY `file_time` LIMIT $start, $per_page")
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is your positioning on your ORDER BY. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE `user_name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}' ORDER BY `file_time` LIMIT $start, $per_page
```